# Differentiation Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am currently reading Constantin and Foias' *Navier-Stokes Equations*. In Chapter 3, he lets $$v_i(x)=\alpha(\psi^{-1}(x))u_i(\psi^{-1}(x)),$$
so that $$v_i(\psi(y))=\alpha(y)u_i(y).$$
Here, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and are related by $\psi(y)=x$. He then differentiates with respect to $y_k$; we assume everything has enough regularity so that this is well-defined. In terms of the left-hand side, I get that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}(v_i(\psi(y))=\sum_m\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \psi_m}(\psi(y))\frac{\partial \psi_m}{\partial y_k}(y),$$
but instead of the $\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \psi_m}(\psi(y))$ term, he has $\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_m}(\psi^{-1}(x))$.

I am unsure how to arrive at the same expression he has. The only thing I've tried that has come close is writing $$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \psi_m}(\psi(y))=\sum_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}(\psi(y))\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial \psi_m}(y),$$
and the second term on the right-hand side should be equal to $\delta_{mj}$, whence the above expression is equivalent to $$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \psi_m}(\psi(y))=\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_m}(\psi(y)),$$
but I still have $\psi(y)$ inside instead of $\psi^{-1}(x)$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please choose a better title. The tags already tells us that the question is about differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

The [copy of C&F that I can find on the web](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eI36TEsH4N8C&pg=PA14&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) actually has $\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_m}(\psi^{-1}(y))$ which is obviously wrong.

I think it should be $\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_m}(\psi(y))$ which would be entirely consistent with what's gone before.

If you have an edition that puts $\psi^{-1}(x)$ there then I suspect someone has tried to correct the mistake and corrected it incorrectly! Applying $v$ to $\psi^{-1}(x)$  would be, so to speak, a type error: $v$ expects to be given an $x$, not a $y$.